# disable "Google Search" on address bar for a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm building an extension to process a query in the address bar but by default, "Google Search" (see image below `Google Search` will handle 
"team/m") will overwrite google chrome extension when pressing `enter`. How do I configure the chrome extension to disable "Google Search" if my prefixes are "team" or "hello".

[image]

Comment: The `omnibox` search API for extensions requires the keyword to be followed by a space character.